# Impact of adding partitions to an existing Kafka topic on producer/consumer behaviour

Tags: apache-kafka

When a new partition is added to a existing topic, how do producers and consumers  behave to adapt this change and what is the strategy to assign the new partition to a broker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For Producers

Producers ***will adapt*** fairly seamlessly to the addition of partitions.

Let's say if you've got 5 partitions at the moment and you decide to add 2 more partitions - if your producer is producing data to partitions in:

1. A round robin fashion, then it will now round robin your messages to 7 partitions instead of 5.
2. A keyed fashion (i.e. messages with the same key ending up in the same partition), then the mapping of the keys to the partitions will adjust.

### For Consumers

Consumers on the other hand ***may not adapt*** and the exact behaviour will heavily depend on the actual set-up of your consumers in consumer groups.

Let's use the same example as above i.e. a topic with 5 partitions and you're adding 2 more and your consumer ***will***:

1. ***Adapt***, if the functionality of your consumer is Generic and does not depend semantically on any particular keys, for example:

   - If you're using a [RoundRobinAssignor](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html) and each consumer is free to consume from any partition
   - If you're using a FailoverAssignor (as described in [this article](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3)) and only one consumer in a group will actively consume
   - There could be more such scenarios...
2. ***Not adapt***, if the functionality of your consumer instances is heavily dependent on the keys of the incoming messages i.e. a consumer instance must consume messages only with a certain key. For such topics, it is highly recommended that the partitions are set at the time of creation and avoid resizing later ([Reference: Kafka Definitive Guide - Chapter 9 Administering Kafka -> Topic Operations -> Adding Partitions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/)).

I've just tried to support the explanation with the above examples but there may be more scenarios.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank, but how is the change be notified to the producers and consumers? and for conumsers , if the change is adapted, will it cause an parititon assignment automatically?

Comment: On the producer side, you may see some warnings indicating that a re-balance has been triggered but it should not cause any data loss. On the consumer side, yes the partitions will be reassigned and there is a method that gets revoked called " onPartitionsAssigned".

Comment: It is because of the reassignment the consumer side is critical because the semantic functioning of the consumer may get affected.

Comment: Great. I'm glad you found it useful. Thanks for acknowledging. :)